# How to save / retrieve nested dictionary in NSUserDefault swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, save, nsuserdefaults

I'm building an app, in which the user is able to create UITableviewcell that will lead to a different UIViewController editable by the user. I save the user information as such:

`level1Dictionary = [String : [String : String]]()`
If the user names a UITableViewCell Dog they segue to the viewController and i set `level1Dictionary[dog] = [String : String]()` I now save the dictionary in NSUserdefaults as such `NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults()setObject(level1Dictionary, forKey: "level1Dictionary")` All works fine.

When i restart the app and press my customCreate UITAbleViewCell named dog i want to retrieve what ever information the user stored in `level1Dictionary = [Dog : [String : String]]`.
I retrieve the information as such within viewdidload: `level1Dictionary = NSUserDefault.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("level1Dictionary") as? [String : String] ?? [String : String]()` but this returns error: Cannot Convert value of type [String : String]? to expected argument type [String : [String : String]]?

Comment: You are saving with the `level1Dictionary` key and retrieving with `totalDictionary` key which is different, right?

Comment: Sorry, i made a spelling mistake i have edited the question. Why is it that i can't just save and retrieve to the same var?

Comment: Try this: `NSUserDefault.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("level1Dictionary") as? [String : [String : String]]?? [String : [String : String]]()`

Comment: It works! Thank you very much Santosh :D

Comment: Glad it worked for you!. Please mark my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSUserDefault.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("level1Dictionary") as? [String : [String : String]]?? [String : [String : String]]()
```